# Using Whisper API to Generate .SRT Transcripts?

Tags: openai-api, openai-whisper, whisper

I'm exploring the capabilities of the Whisper API and was wondering if it can be used to generate an .SRT file with transcriptions. From what I understand, this transcription to .SRT can be achieved when running the model locally using the Whisper package. Unfortunately, I don't possess the computational resources to run the model locally, so I'm leaning towards using the API directly.

Has anyone had experience with this or can provide guidance on how to approach it through the API?

```
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = API_KEY
audio_file = open("audio.mp3", "rb")
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file)
print(transcript.text)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cursory look at [OpenAI's docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/createTranscription#response_format) shows that `srt` is a supported value for the `response_format` parameter on the `/v1/audio/transcriptions` endpoint.

With the official Python bindings you're using in your example, you should be able to pass this as a named parameter to your `openai.Audio.transcribe()` invocation:

```
transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file, response_format="srt")
```